# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for admob interstitials on some devices

Tags: gradle, admob

Play Store reports crashes on newest AdMob on some devices:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
  at jq.b (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):3)
  at jp.a (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):3)
  at jr.a (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):19)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.ar.a (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):15)
  at iu.a (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):20)
  at iu.run (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)
  at ad.loadClass (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):4)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
```

I have upgraded my gradle file to use the newest targetSdkVersion 28 and newest AdMob SDK 17.2.0. But I had conflict problems with different versions of com.android.support libraries. I was able to compile properly by "forcing" com.android.support libraries in version 28.0.0. Maybe this is causing the issue? I am not doing anything fancy, just including admob, facebook, firebase, ... The same app code works without crashes for older targetSdkVersion.

Also I noticed there is the possibility to add the ads over firebase which uses different lib implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.2.0' and different classes and requries different data in manifest.

Here is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 373
        versionName "4.0.6"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    flavorDimensions "tier"
    productFlavors {
       playStoreFree {
            ...
            dimension "tier"
        }

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation project(':SliderPreference')
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.44'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.31.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

In Manifest I have

```
<application ...
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AD_MANAGER_APP"
            android:value="true"/>
...
```

Main activity:

```
InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
MobileAds.initialize(context, BuildConfig.AD_APP_ID);
        MobileAds.setAppMuted(true);

        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd (this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(BuildConfig.AD_UNIT_ID);

        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                Log.d("AD", "onAdFailedToLoad: "+String.valueOf(errorCode));
                super.onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                Log.d("AD", "onAdLoaded: ");
                super.onAdLoaded();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                    requestNewInterstitial();
            }
        });
        requestNewInterstitial();
    }
}


private void requestNewInterstitial() {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer from Admob:

Thanks for reaching out to us. Our team has a fix in place for this issue. The fix should be available in the future releases of the SDK. Please keep an eye on our release history page for more updates.

Comment: This continues happening to me in the most recent release of their sdk

Comment: Same as @Genaut ... I read we got to add the http legacy thing but then I read the maps API had the same bug and was fixed in the SDK.... I assumed it fixed admob too but apparently we still get the bug... Im using SDK version 17.2....